# how to compare datetime.datetime and pyodbc.row values

Tags: python, openpyxl, pyodbc

I am trying to  see if values in DateRef row in Access database is equal to datetime.datetime value in Excell cell. Cannot wrap my head around how to convert pyodbc.row to datetime.datetime.

```
In[18]:sheet['BL2'].value
Out[18]: datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 15, 0, 0)

In[21]type(sheet['BL2'].value)
Out[21]: datetime.datetime



In [17]: DateRef_aslist[-1]
In [17]: (datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 15, 0, 0), )

In [20]: type(DateRef_aslist[-1])
In [20]: Out[20]: pyodbc.Row

In [19]: DateRef_aslist[-1] == sheet['BL2'].value
Out[19]: False
```

Comment: Try `type(DateRef_aslist[-1][0])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Row` is a collection.  Yours only contain one element.  So try this:

```
DateRef_aslist[-1][0] == sheet['BL2'].value
```

Sometimes when I write a query that selects one column I think the cursor is going to yield one object (as opposed to a collection of one object).  But this would mean the cursor has to yield one type when the query selects one column and another type when the query selects more than one.

Eventually it's easier to remember it always yields a `Row`.

Comment: ( cc: @Luka ) Tip: When running a query that will return a single value we can use `.fetchval()` instead of `.fetchone()` to simply return the value.